# Отправка данных формы в телеграм

Tags: php, wordpress, form, elementor

Создал чат бот и небольшой квиз для теста. https://sitestore.com.ua/
Использую сайт на Wordpress + Elementor. Для создания квиза и формы PAFE Form.
Для логики... плагин Code Snipets.
При использовании родных форм все срабатывает идеально, но при использовании PAFE Form, в телеграм заявка не приходит. Скорее всего с переменными, ид, ... что-то путаю, подставлял разное, но не получается. Может кто-то с наметаным глагом подскажет или укажет на ошибки.
В самом коде указан код который использую в Code Snipets
Спасибо

add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {

```
$bot_token = "5911696913:AAFGa49b1K5jAPWN9gnPSbeybANSDIZgAe8"; // Вставьте между кавычками токен вашего бота
$chat_id = "-870641174"; // Вставьте между кавычками ID чата, в который должны приходить заявки и не забудьте минус
$form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' ); // Берет из настроек формы название формы и записывает её в переменную $form_name
$form_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
$arr = array();
$txt = $form_name . "%0A"; // Выводит в заголовке формы данные из переменной $form_name

    foreach ( $form_fields as $id => $field ) {
      $txt .= "<b>".$field['title']."</b>: ".$field['value']."%0A";
    }

fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}&disable_web_page_preview=true","r"); // Открывает ссылку, по которой и уходит нужный текст в телеграм
```

}, 10, 2 );